# Jenkins Slave VM Can not Clone Git Repo

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I have a virtual windows machine running windows server 2003. This is a set up as a slave in jenkins. Every time I try to run a job on this slave it fails with a timeout.

For the slave I have set a tool path to `C:\Git\cmd\git.exe` and on master, I have jenkins server the git path is set as well.

On the slave in command prompt all the git commands work, I am able to clone the repo. The ssh keys are set, the job settings work on another slave running windows 7 (not a vm).

Can you run a jenkins test on a VM? At this point all I can think is that jenkins fails on VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the only thing I needed to do was right click and view the the Jenkins Service Properties

Select the log on tab, select "This Account" and add the system admins credentials!